# Why can't I assign arrays as &a = &b?

Tags: c

I have a problem assigning an array like:

```
int a[];
int b[] = {1,2,3};
&a = &b;
```

I know I could use pointers but I want to try it that way...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't assign arrays in C.  You can copy them with the `memcpy()` function, declared in `<string.h>`:

```
int a[3];
int b[] = {1,2,3};

memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: The `&array` is a deliberate choice - when copying a single object (here, a single array), I think the form `memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof src)` should be preferred (or with `sizeof dest` - they should be the same).  This is for consistency - the same `memcpy()` line would work if the type of `a` and `b` were a non-array type.  You may not agree, but hopefully you can see that there is certainly "judgement" behind the choice.

Comment: @weberc2: It is, and `sizeof a` is the size of the array.

Comment: Why does it need a pointer to a pointer? Isn't it enough to have a pointer to the array?

Comment: @weberc2: There is no pointer to a pointer anywhere in that answer.  `&a` *is* a pointer to the array, as you said yourself.

Comment: @caf I think you misunderstood me, I said `a pointer to a pointer to an array`, to which you replied, `it is`. But thank you for clarifying, I understand now.

Comment: @weberc2: Ahh yes, you're right - I misread your comment.  `&a` is just a pointer to the array.

Answer (score 17):

That way doesn't work, as you have found.  You cannot assign arrays in C.

Structs, however, are assignable.  So you can do this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x[3];
} T;

T a;
T b = { { 1, 2, 3 } };

a = b;
```

Comment: Thanks this was straight, is there any function doing this job, so i dont have to rewrite lot of code.

Comment: Okay, i tried this: ´T a[]; T b[] = { { 1, 2, 3 } }; a = b;´ ,its still not working. Output: "Expression is no lvalue".

Comment: @Starfighter911: That's not the code I wrote!  Simply `T a;`, not `T a[];`.