# Why can't arrays of same type and size be assigned?

Tags: c, arrays

If I declare two arrays - `arr1` and `arr2` - of, say, type `int` of size 10 each, and initialize first array, and I wish to create a copy of `arr1` in `arr2`; why can't I just give the instruction `arr2 = arr1` ?

I know two structures of same type can be assigned. Why is that not the case with arrays?

Comment: Because of array decay. What does that mean?

Comment: because that's not how the language was defined!!

Comment: arrays are actually constant pointers. They cannot be modified.

Comment: @sgar91: Arrays are not constant pointers; they are arrays.

Comment: For a workaround, see [Why declare a struct that only contains an array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966570/why-declare-a-struct-that-only-contains-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882735/why-cant-i-assign-arrays-as-a-b

Comment: I guess the real answer is, arrays were too complicated even for the inventors of the language and never got around to implement it later. The same reason C can't do `int x[9] = {3};` correctly, even though it can do `int x[9] = {0};` and can't declare functions in local scope even though a local scope function is nothing more than an array of bytes, like a string with return instruction being it's null terminator; granted returning them has the same issues as returning a pointer to a local string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with arrays is that in all expressions (except when passed to the `sizeof` and the unary `&` operators) they convert to a pointer to their first element.

So, supposing you have:

```
int arr1[10];
int arr2[10];
...
```

Then if you write something like

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

you are actually attempting to do this:

```
arr1 = &arr2[0];
```

or this:

```
&arr1[0] = &arr2[0];
```

In both cases you have a problem preventing your code from compiling. In the former case you're attempting to assign between two incompatible types (array vs pointer), while in the latter case you're attempting to modify a constant pointer (`&arr1[0]`).

Comment: Is `arr1 = arr2` the same as `arr1[0] = arr2`, which wouldn't work?

Comment: @Gnuey Different. Neither will work. You simply can't assign arrays to one another with the assignment operator in C. Period.

Comment: Why was the language designed like that? Why not make the decay only when necessary (e.g. assigning to a pointer)?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 It's just one of the many little oversights, not critical to the language success.

Answer (score 8):

Actually they can, but in indirect way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int arr1[3] = {0};
  int arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3};

  struct tmp{
      int arr[3];
  };

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  // casting array to address of struct
  // before dereferencing & asigning to it
  *(struct tmp*)arr1 = *(struct tmp*)arr2;

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

You can even make it in a little-bit more generic way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRUCT_TO(type, size) struct temp##__LINE__{type arr[size];}; *(struct temp##__LINE__*)
#define STRUCT_FROM *(struct temp##__LINE__*)

int main(){
  int arr1[3] = {0};
  int arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3};

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  STRUCT_TO(int,3) arr1 = STRUCT_FROM arr2;

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

Or ... if we can sacrifice some portability, then we can make syntax a little-bit
more symmetrical:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
#define TEMP_STRUCT struct temp##__LINE__
#define AS_STRUCT_DESTINATION(arr) TEMP_STRUCT{typeof(arr[0]) arrTmp[ARRAY_LENGTH(arr)];}; *(TEMP_STRUCT*) arr
#define AS_STRUCT_SOURCE(arr) *(TEMP_STRUCT*) arr

int main(){
  int arr1[3] = {0};
  int arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3};

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  AS_STRUCT_DESTINATION(arr1) = AS_STRUCT_SOURCE(arr2);

  printf("%d %d %d\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice! granted, `char x[1] = {'a'}; *((char (*)[1])&x = *(char (*)[1])&x;` would be a bit more elegant than `char x[1] = {'a'}; typedef struct { float m[16]; } tDF0DC30A_DE98_4357_9E27_E18720AA1C1F; *(tDF0DC30A_DE98_4357_9E27_E18720AA1C1F *)x = *(tDF0DC30A_DE98_4357_9E27_E18720AA1C1F *)x;` But I guess you can generalize it with a macro...

Comment: like this `char x[1] = {'a'}; [NEWLINE] #define ARRAYCOPY(UNIQID, size, DST, SRC) typedef struct { char x[size]; } UNIQID; *(UNIQID *)DST = *(UNIQID *)SRC [NEWLINE] ARRAYCOPY(tAF0DC30A_DE98_4357_9E27_E18720AA1C1F, 1, x, x);`

Comment: basically, this allows you to copy 4x4 matrix rows without looping and without many copy statements. `#define ARRAYCOPY(UNIQID, size, DST, SRC) typedef struct { char x[size]; } UNIQID; *(UNIQID *)(DST) = *(UNIQID *)(SRC);[NEWLINE] ARRAYCOPY(nsijdiq0000, 16*4, &m2, &m); ARRAYCOPY(nsijdiq0001, 4*4, m2, m+4); ARRAYCOPY(nsijdiq0002, 4*4, m2+4, m);` where m,m2 are `float pointers or names of float[16] arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array into another as you would do if your variables were pointers to an array. Even in this case, you would not create a copy, but only another pointer to the same array.

To copy an array, you should copy the whole content using memcpy():

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[3];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: I did not mean that arrays were pointers (that's why i said that he cannot assign arrays, but pointers). But I think that a part of his question is how to copy an array, and that's what I tried to answer to. I edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: `To copy an array, you should copy the whole content using memcpy():` what if the array is an array of a single character; "should" you really copy the character into register, push register on stack, push pc, jump to memcpy, have it do its thing, set register to the address of the destination(since memcpy has a return value), pop pc and jump back to it, and either it, or you has to take that 4 byte argument "character" off the stack by adding to it. All that just to copy 1 character from one memory location to another could be avoided if `*(char(*)[1])x = *(char(*)[1])x` was valid C;

Comment: `char c1[4] = "yes"; char c2[4]; /*newline*/ #define ARRAYCOPY(UNIQID, size, DST, SRC) typedef struct { char x[size]; } UNIQID; *(UNIQID *)(DST) = *(UNIQID *)(SRC); /*newline */ ARRAYCOPY(blah0000, 4, c2, c1); puts(c2);` does just that, but requires a unique "typename" each time you call it, but in the above, the compiler is free to optimize the copy to a single fetch and a single store. no jumps, no loops.

Comment: @Dmitry You wouldn't need anything like `*(char(*)[1])y = *(char(*)[1])x`, you'd need `y[0] = x[0]`.  Also, you could copy an array using `#define ARRAYCOPY(size, DST, SRC) for(int i=0;i<size;i++){DST[i]=SRC[i]}` if you wanted to.

Comment: my concern was with expressing "copy this chunk of memory from here to there" also, for loop isnt ok because you are explicitly saying the chunk size being copied, so the compiler isn't able to optimize the chunk size to the current platform, which c excels at. the example above tells the compiler to treat the array as a single structure and let's compiler figure out how to copy it.

Comment: tldr i meant without using for loop and without using functions, just trick compiler to manually assign the fields inline using best method it knows

Answer (score -1):

In C, array type does not hold size, so if `a` has type `int[]` and `b` has type `int[]` than to calculate `a == b` we need to know actual sizes of `a` and `b` which are not known neither in compile time nor in run time.

Comment: But the question asks about the type `int[10]`, not the incomplete type `int[]`.