# In C, why can't I assign a string to a char array after it's declared?

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, assign

This has been bugging me for a while.

```
struct person {
       char name[15];
       int age;
};
struct person me;
me.name = "nikol";
```

when I compile I get this error:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[15]’ from type ‘char *’

am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Are you asking how to do the initialization?  `struct person me = {"nikol", 3};` should work.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826952/why-cant-arrays-of-same-type-and-size-be-assigned

Comment: [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37225244/2173917). _Disclaimer: My answer_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Arrays are second-class citizens in C, they do not support assignment.

```
char x[] = "This is initialization, not assignment, thus ok.";
```

This does not work:

```
x = "Compilation-error here, tried to assign to an array.";
```

Use library-functions or manually copy every element for itself:

```
#include <string.h>
strcpy(x, "The library-solution to string-assignment.");
```

Comment: I mixed up initialization and assignment, sorry. Yes, this solves it, thank you. I was led to the wrong path by a example from the teacher (which I now see is wrong).

Answer (score 9):

`me.name = "nikol";` is wrong !! you need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

when you do `x = "Some String"`, actually you are putting the starting address of the static string `"Some String"` into variable `x`. In your case, `name` is a static array, and you cannot change the address. What you need, is to copy your string to the already allocated array `name`. For that, use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to know the following points:

- In C, text strings are just arrays.
- In C, array variables are *basically* just pointers.

So, `char mytext[12];` is essentially just declaring a char pointer called `mytext` that stores the address of the first (zero'th) element of the array/string.

This code is therefore valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char a[] = "Hello";
    const char *b = a;
    printf("%s\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

The important thing to note here is that re-assigning `b` doesn't change the *contents* of whatever it points to - it changes *the thing* that it points to.

However, there *are* cases where arrays and pointers behave differently. In the example above, `a` cannot be reassigned. If you try, [you'll get an error](http://codepad.org/so6ktkb3).

To go back to you original example, this structure:

```
struct person{
    char name[15];
    int age;
};
```

...can be thought of as a 19-byte structure* of which the first 15 bytes are earmarked for storing a string. The `name` attribute stores the address of the first byte, so you know where those 15 bytes live in memory - you just need to write something useful into them.

This is where functions such as `sprintf()` or `strcpy()` come into play - they copy data into **the address defined by** `name` rather than re-assigning `name` itself.

* Assuming that `sizeof(int)` is 4 and the structure is not padded, of course...

Comment: the size of the example struct is 20 Bytes. There is a padding byte between the array and the int.

Comment: You are indeed [correct](http://codepad.org/W5qGYWsD) - I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I was right the first time - it's 19 bytes [without padding](http://codepad.org/hEbc7c9y), as I said originally.

Comment: @Martin James I didn't say that they were identical (hence why I emphasised the word *basically* in my second bullet-point, and pointed out that "there are cases where arrays and pointers behave differently" later on), but please feel free to edit the post if you think that the answer I gave could be more clear on this point.

Comment: You are off to a really bad start when you do not clearly differentiate between arrays and pointers. And in C strings are 0-terminated sequences.

Comment: @Deduplicator I do know the difference now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @KokNikol: Actually, I meant GoBusto, as his post does not really reflect that. Yes, he later mentions one difference, but that's too little (there are more) and too late (he sets the tone at the start, and too many will miss that).

Answer (score 0):

**You first must understand how memory assignment work in array**.

When you declare the name of an array, that name actually works as pointer
and point to the first element of the array.

```
struct person {
       char name[15];
       int age;
};
```

Here *name* is pointing to the memory address of first element of array i.e. *name[0]*.
You have declare the character array so the each block of memory have 1 byte of size. And *name* is also pointing to the 1 byte of memory.

```
struct person me;
me.name = "nikol";
```

me.name = "nikol"; won't work. You are assigning 5 byte of data to 1 byte of storage and also without dereferencing the the pointer variable.
For better understanding try this code

```
struct person me;
*me.name = 'n';
```

Here I have deference the pointer *name* and assigned 1 byte of data. This code will work perfectly fine

```
printf("%c" , me.name[0]);
```

Output will be n.

This is why we have to use strcpy() function. Strcpy() assign the each character of the string constant to the each block of memory of the array. This is why it will work.

```
strcpy(me.name , "nikol");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) function (of **`string.h`** library) :)

```
main(){
struct person{
       char name[15];
       int age;
};
struct person me;
strcpy(me.name,"nikol");
}
```

Comment: FYI: `string.h` is a header, not a library.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to change the memory address of an array pointer (by giving me.name = "nikol") which is impossible. Name of array (me.name) is a fixed pointer and cannot be changed to point to a new location of string ("nikol") because  memory address of an array pointer is on the first member of that array. If you want to assign a string after declared (me.name = "nikol"), use external pointer *name instead because external pointer floats outside array so its value can be changed on-the-fly.

```
struct person {
       char *name;
       int age;
};
struct person me;
me.name = "nikol"; // no error
```