# "error: assignment to expression with array type error" when I assign a struct field (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, initialization

I'm a beginner C programmer, yesterday I learned the use of C structs and the possible application of these ones about the resolution of specific problems. However when I was experimenting with my C IDE (Codeblocks 16.01) in order to learn this aspect of C programming, I've encountered a strange issue. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 30

typedef struct{
     char name[N];
     char surname[N];
     int age;
} data;

int main() {
     data s1;
     s1.name="Paolo";
     s1.surname = "Rossi";
     s1.age = 19;
     getchar();
     return 0;
}
```

During the compilation, the compiler (GCC 4.9.3-1 under Windows) reported me an error that says

> "error: assignment to expression with array type error"

on instruction

```
s1.name="Paolo" 
s1.surname="Rossi"
```

while if I do

```
data s1 = {"Paolo", "Rossi", 19};
```

it works. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've discovered one of the differences between assignment and initialization.

Comment: Can you be more specific? thanks ;)

Comment: You can write `s1 = (const data){"Paolo", "Rossi", 19};`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are facing issue in

```
 s1.name="Paolo";
```

because, in the LHS, you're using an *array* type, which is not *assignable*.

To elaborate, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and, regarding the *modifiable lvalue*, from chapter §6.3.2.1

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type, [...]

You need to use `strcpy()` to *copy into* the array.

That said, `data s1 = {"Paolo", "Rossi", 19};` works fine, because this is not a direct *assignment* involving assignment operator. There we're using a *brace-enclosed initializer list* to provide the initial values of the *object*. That follows the law of initialization, as mentioned in chapter §6.7.9

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.[....]

Comment: If i habe `char *b = "Hello"` , and if i have `char c[] = "hello"` , both works , if for first case i do `b = "helloworld"` , it works too , but for second case if i do `c = "helloworld"` , it does not why so ?

Comment: @SurajJain that is exactly what is explained in the answer. You cannot assign to an array.

Answer (score 54):

```
typedef struct{
     char name[30];
     char surname[30];
     int age;
} data;
```

defines that `data` should be a block of memory that fits 60 chars plus 4 for the int (see note)

```
[----------------------------,------------------------------,----]
 ^ this is name              ^ this is surname              ^ this is age
```

This allocates the memory on the stack.

```
data s1;
```

Assignments just copies numbers, sometimes pointers.

This fails

```
s1.name = "Paulo";
```

because the compiler knows that `s1.name` is the start of a struct 64 bytes long, and `"Paulo"` is a char[] 6 bytes long (6 because of the trailing \0 in C strings)
Thus, trying to assign a pointer to a string into a string.

To copy "Paulo" *into* the struct at the point `name` and "Rossi" *into* the struct at point `surname`.

```
memcpy(s1.name,    "Paulo", 6);
memcpy(s1.surname, "Rossi", 6);
s1.age = 1;
```

You end up with

```
[Paulo0----------------------,Rossi0-------------------------,0001]
```

`strcpy` does the same thing but it knows about `\0` termination so does not need the length hardcoded.

Alternatively you can define a struct which *points to* char arrays of any length.

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
  char *surname;
  int age;
} data;
```

This will create

```
[----,----,----]
```

This will now work because you are filling the struct with pointers.

```
s1.name = "Paulo";
s1.surname = "Rossi";
s1.age = 1;
```

Something like this

```
[---4,--10,---1]
```

Where 4 and 10 are pointers.

Note: the ints and pointers can be different sizes, the sizes 4 above are 32bit as an example.

Answer (score 21):

Please check this example here: [Accessing Structure Members](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

There is explained that the right way to do it is like this:

```
strcpy(s1.name , "Egzona");
printf( "Name : %s\n", s1.name);
```

Comment: this has an extra function call overhead(which compilers can choose to inline but generally don't), which does a loop rather than inline, and this loop isnt eliminated if the machine you're compiling on can copy the whole thing in one move, it always does at least one iteration. This seems like it cannot be solved without preprocessing the source code since C won't do it for you. `char x[2] = {'h', 0}; *(char (*)[2])&x = *(char (*)[2])&x;` should be significantly faster than `strcpy(x, x, 2)` if it was valid C.

Answer (score 0):

Use strcpy() function for modifying the value. Because directly assigning value to a string is not possible in C.(Not Assignable error will show).

```
strcpy(s1.name, "New_Name");
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39307001/2227743).

Answer (score 0):

you get error because you are trying to change a constant. when we initialize a string like `char sample[20];` , the `sample` itself is a **constant** pointer which means you can change the value of the thing that pointer is pointing to, but you can't change the value of the pointer itself! when you initialize `char sample` it is like `sample` as a pointer is initialized as`char* const sample;` and when you try to do this:`s1.name="paulo";` you are actually trying to change the strings address. in fact when you compile and run your program the string `"paulo"` fills part of your memory independent of `s1.name`. to understand better you can run the following code : `#include <stdio.h> int main() { char name[20]; printf("address of sample:%d  address of a random string:%d",name,"paolo");  }` the output will give you two independent addresses like X and Y. X is the address of `s1.name` and Y is the address of `paulo`. you can't change X to Y since it is a constant.