# How would I assign a character to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm making a radix converter and I wanted to use linked list to do this because I'm new to data structures. When I assign my character to the pointer the compiler give a "error: assignment to expression with array type" error.

```
struct node
{

  char bin_num[25];

  struct node *next;
};

char conversion[50] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$/^&*";
typedef struct node NODE;


NODE *head = NULL;

int insert (int num){

  NODE *temp;

  temp = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof (NODE));
  temp->bin_num = conversion[num];//Need help with this line


  temp->next = NULL;

  if (head == NULL)
    {

      head = temp;

    }

  else
    {

      temp->next = head;

      head = temp;

    }

}


//This is not the entire code
```

Comment: `temp->bin_num = conversion[num];` what do you want to do here? the LHS is of type `char [25]`, and the RHS is miost likely a `char`...they are certainly not compatible.

Comment: `bin_num` is an array, not a pointer. It isn't clear why it is an array rather than just a `char`, or what you're trying to do with that line.

Comment: `temp->bin_num = conversion[num];` maybe if `bin_num` was declared as an actual pointer and not as an array... Also, why do you need it as a pointer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["error: assignment to expression with array type error" when I assign a struct field (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225244/error-assignment-to-expression-with-array-type-error-when-i-assign-a-struct-f)

Comment: @Yathartha Do you want to assign just one character to the array bin_num or a substring of num characters of the array conversion? In the first case it is unclear why you declared a whole character array in NODE instead of a variable of the type  char.

Comment: It's unclear why you would use a linked list for radix conversion. Use linked lists when they are appropriate. But anyway you probably want `char bin_num[25]` -> `char bin_num`.

Comment: The main reason why I wanted to add the char conversion line was so that when I get a remainder for the radix I'd just look at the index and add it to the stack. Eg: converting 14 to base 16 would be E. 14%16 = 14 conversion[14] is E and so I add that back to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

So `conversion` is a `char *`; it's value when not using an index (within `[]`) is a pointer at the beginning of the character array.

If `temp->bin_num` is also `char *` you can pass a pointer to a specific position into the `conversion` array using:

```
temp->bin_num = conversion + num;
```

Be aware though that you will now have a pointer to the remainder of the character array. That pointer will have to be de-referenced on use, ex: `printf("%c\n", *temp->bin_num);`.