# How to initialize these array types?

Tags: c, arrays, string, typedef, c-strings

I'm doing a work and I got a bit of code handed to me with some "string" typedef to make use of strings easier, but now I'm having some trouble understanding the code and how it works.
Can you guys help me?

```
//----------- THIS IS THE CODE HANDED TO ME -----------------------------

#define MAX_STRING          256
#define MAX_STRING_VECTOR   1024

typedef char String[MAX_STRING];
typedef String StringVector[MAX_STRING_VECTOR];

//----------- THIS IS THE CODE I WROTE -----------------------------

StringVector strV;
String str;

*str = "Hello";
*(strV) = str;
```

The error it shows is "assignment to expression with array type".

Thank you guys!

Comment: yes that's what I meant, I was copying the code from anther computer, but the error still exists like that :(

Comment: `str` is array of char; its elements are of type char, ie `str[0]`, `str[1]`, ... have type char. `str[0]` and `*str` are equivalent, so type of `*str` is char: you cannot assign `"Hello"` to a char. Either set one element at a time with `str[0] = 'H'; str[1] = 'e'; /*...*/ str[4] = 'o'; str[5] = '\0';` or use the `strcpy(str, "Hello");`

Comment: See [“error: assignment to expression with array type error” when I assign a struct field (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37225244/10077).

Comment: To _iniitialize_ `str`, `String str;

*str = "Hello";` --> `String str = "Hello";`

Comment: TBH such kind of typedef for a string usage in C does not provide clarity to the code. You can simply use normal char array for string.

Comment: Needless to say, this is great for [obfuscation](https://www.ioccc.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C syntax, it is not allowed to assign an array of `char`, such as `str` is here, with a string literal except for initializing.

Rather use `strcpy` to assign a string to an array. For initializing `str` by `Hello` use `String str = "Hello";`.

For example:

```
StringVector strV;
String str = "Hello";

strcpy(*strV, str);
```

[Online Example](https://godbolt.org/z/gYo8Do)

Or if `str` is not needed:

```
StringVector strV;

strcpy(*strV, "Hello");
```

---

Note: `strcpy()` is declared in the header `<string.h>`.

Comment: thank you all very much, this got me to where I wanted in the code