# How to store a byte array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to store an array of bytes with fixed size in C as a variable. The following code was my attempt:

```
unsigned char bytes_array[4]
bytes_array = 0x12345678
```

However, I got this error "assignment to expression with array type". How can I solve this issue? And how can I print out the bytes array as it is? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["error: assignment to expression with array type error" when I assign a struct field (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225244/error-assignment-to-expression-with-array-type-error-when-i-assign-a-struct-f)

Comment: @dboy Thank you. I tried this solution. It worked fine with strings, but I still couldn't find a method to store "pure bytes" like 0x1234. These bytes come directly from sensor readings.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char bytes_array[] = { 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 };
```

Comment: @TomKarzes very good comment brilliant spotted, the answer would be so totally unusable with the incorrect values. Did you ask about the endianess of the intended system?

Comment: Thank you. Is the only method to store bytes, that I have to assign them to an array one byte at a time? So if I want to store 0x12345678(from sensor reading), it must be parsed first?

Comment: @JerryYang : you would only be able to „concatenate“ char to build string. I guess you want to preserve the char as it is.