# Why is not possible to assign a pointer to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, assignment-operator

In C, I'm coding this

```
char * real = strdup("GEORGE");
char one[1024];
one = real;
```

and it gives error:

> invalid initializer

any suggestions?
is there any chance I can make array of chars equal to char pointer?

Comment: Try `strcpy(one,real);`.

Comment: And BTW, you may as well write `char one[] = "GEORGE"`.

Comment: Related: [Why can't arrays of same type and size be assigned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826952/why-cant-arrays-of-same-type-and-size-be-assigned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `one` is a variable of type array. Thus,

```
 one = real;
```

is attempt to assign to an array type, which is not allowed.

To elaborate, array names are no modifiable lvalues and assignment operator only works on modifiable lvalues as the LHS operand.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and then, chapter §6.3.2.1, (*emphais mine*)

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that
>   **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const qualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const qualified
>   type.

You need to use [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content to the array.

Answer (score 3):

C requires constants in array initializers. You are allowed to do this:

```
char one[1024] = "GEORGE";
```

or this

```
char one[1024] = {'G','E','O','R','G','E'};
```

but assigning a pointer to an array is *not* allowed under any circumstances, initializer or not.

On the other hand, you can *copy* a content of a `char` pointer into an array. Depending on whether your source array is null-terminated or not, you can use `strcpy` or `memcpy`, like this:

```
strcpy(one, real);
```

or

```
memcpy(one, real, 7);
```

Comment: Very right sir, but are we sure OP wants _initialization_? from the snippet, it more looks like an assigment to me.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The error description "invalid initializer" suggests that the code snippet shown in the OP is not exactly what he is trying to achieve in real code. That's why I started with initialization, before covering the "impossible assignment".

Comment: true that, Agree.