# Assigning a return value to an int array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memcpy

I am attempting to copy a return value from a method into an array of ints. (The method `getPixelArray` returns an int array of size 3.) Below is the offending section of my code. When I try to compile this code, I get the error

`invalid lvalue in unary '&'`

What could be going on? I was following the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7883036/1696230) answer.

```
int temp[3];
memcpy(&temp, &(getPixelColor(width, height, x, y)), sizeof(temp));
```

EDIT: Here is the method.

```
int[3] getPixelColor(int width, int height, float x, float y) {
    int color[3] = {0, 0, 0}; // color of pixel

    // get color (omitted)

    return color;
}
```

Comment: `(getPixelColor(width, height, x, y))` is not an lvalue

Comment: Please post the code for `getPixelColor()` or at least its function prototype.

Comment: Sorry. I have posted the skeleton of the function.

Comment: this code is just plain wrong. you can't return an array (nor can you return a pointer to a local automatic variable). And you can **never** treat a function's return value as an lvalue in C.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `tmp` behaves like an int pointer.

And you cannot even return an array from a function, just a pointer:

```
int *getPixelCOlor(...

memcpy(temp, getPixelColor(width, height, x, y), sizeof temp);
```

getPixelColor returns the address of local automatic storage, which is usually in its stack frame, and will be destroyed with any subsequent function call. Like your own `memcpy`. Here be dragons.