# generating random color within an array and storing it in struct

Tags: c, arrays, random, struct

Hi i want to be able randomly select a given set of color and store it into an struct of array.

```
void addrand(struct inv[],int *ptr)

const char *random[6];
            random[0] = "red";
            random[1] = "green";
            random[2] = "yellow";
            random[3] = "blue";
            random[4] = "white";
            random[5] = "black";

inv[*ptr].color = random[rand()%6];
```

i get something like array type 'char[30]' is not assignable.

Comment: You need [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: You can store only the pointer, instead or simply the random index.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp im still a bit unsure after reading the recommended post. Can you elaborate bit?

Comment: You can't assign an array. What you can do is copy the contents of one array to another (assuming enough space) and that is what `strcpy` does. Here's another q that addresses this: [Why can't I assign arrays as &a = &b?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7882735/669576).